# number of non zero entries in the jordan cann

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this equation $\frac{dy}{dt}=A\frac{t}{y^2}-B\frac{1}{y}$

***My Idea :-***

Suppose let $\frac{1}{y}=x\rightarrow y'=-\frac{1}{x^2}x'$

then given equation reduces to $-\frac{1}{x^2}x'=-Atx^2-Bx$

again i got nonlinear equation any help please

Comment: what are the numbers $A,B$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner..they are just constansts

Comment: it is a nonlinear equation, a numerical method can help here

Comment: May I ask about the source of this differential equation? It might help, when trying to solve it.